# Changing an eloquent object value when iterating

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

To simplify the problem, as I am iterating through the array of objects returned by the eloquent query, when I attempt to change one of it's property it seems to be changing of all their properties.

Assuming fruits is the data returned from the eloquent query

```
var fruits =[{name:apple,nested_relationship:{price:$5},{name:pear,{price:$6},{name:grape}]

foreach ($fruits as fruit){
  if($fruit->name == 'apple'){
     $fruit->nested_relationship->color = 'red';
  }
  elseif($fruit->name == 'grape'){
     $fruit->nested_relationship->color = 'green';
  }
}
```

The final result seems to be `[{name:'apple',nested_relationship:{price:$5,color:'green'}},{name:pear,nested_relationship:{price:$5,color:'green'}},},{name:'grape'}]`

Can someone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: Can't find the problem here. I think we need to have a look in your original code.

Comment: @ya-cha i made some edits to better reflect the situtation. Could the nested relationship be what is causing the issue?

Comment: Is nested_relationship maybe both time the same relation?

Comment: @ya-cha what do you mean? and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463617/looping-and-changing-value-of-nested-eloquent-relationship might be a better representation of the problem, please help me out if possible

Comment: and @ya-cha if the relation is the same, is it possible to edit one without editing the other

Comment: @YeoBryan based on your comment above and in response to Muhammad's answer below, it sounds like you need to update your question so that the code properly represents the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution:**

Use setAttribute() to add new atribute.

```
var fruits =[{name:apple,nested_relationship:{price:$5},{name:pear,{price:$6},{name:grape}]

foreach ($fruits as $fruit){
  if($fruit->name == 'apple'){
     $fruit->nested_relationship->setAttribute('color', 'red');
  }
  elseif($fruit->name == 'grape'){
     $fruit->nested_relationship->setAttribute('color', 'green');
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly it doesnt work, I have a feeling its changing the value of the reference fruit but when error_logging the $fruits, the change is reflected wrongly

Comment: what is your expected and current output ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463617/looping-and-changing-value-of-nested-eloquent-relationship. This might be a better example of the problem, please do help me out